# Android - setContentView doesn't find R layouts

Tags: android, r.java-file, setcontentview

So i'm having some problems, my setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface_gps); doesn't seem to find the xml file, though it's there, and also it is in the R layout procedure:

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_gps_interface=0x7f030000;
    public static final int activity_gps_log=0x7f030001;
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f030002;
    public static final int map=0x7f030003;
}
```

It was all working fine, untile i updated android tools in the sdk manager, so far i reinstalled the adb, but now, this seems to be the new problem. All my project gone error. Any ideas? :(

Comment: check the filename. In R.layout, the name is ..gps_interface.

Comment: I had to delete import R.java, everything works fine now